# Way to take ssh terminal grep result to your current one

Tags: ssh, grep, terminal

im currently working with rather much grepping. The problem is that i do that on remote servers via ssh connection. Is there any way to get the command result (i often do much pipe-lining in my searches to format the result) into my own terminal or maybe even a file on my computer?

Answer (score 3):

You can run the command on remote server over ssh connection without ssh the server

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1 "Command you want to run on the remote server" > <filename>
```

For Jump box server you can use `ProxyCommand` in `.ssh/config`:

```
Host <target server name>
    HostName <target ip address>
    ProxyCommand ssh <jump box user>@<jump box ip> -W %h:%p
    User    <target user>
```

Then you can check:

```
ssh -A <target server name> "command"
```

Comment: Will this work with some additional ssh jumps in between? Because i have to access the server i'm working on via a jump and i don't know if i even have access to the proper address since i have to do it via a daemon.

Comment: @Animu Check the edit for jumpbox server

Answer (score 1):

`grep` will process its standard input stream, and `ssh` may be used to execute a command remotely that generates output.  This output can be processed locally by `grep` and redirected to a local file:

```
ssh ...some options... some_command | grep ...options etc... >outputfile
```

For example,

```
ssh user@server cat file1 file2 file3 | grep 'pattern' >localfile
```